# A stone tied with string, rotated in circle. Is this type of motion is rotational or circular?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, terminology, definition, rotational-kinematics, rotation

I've confusion in this question because circular motion is defined for point masses while rotational motion is for rigid bodies.

And also of if we consider a particle of that stone, it seems that it's performing circular motion, while at the same time if we consider the whole stone it's doing rotational motion about the axis to which string is tied with one end.

Please clarify and give some major points that how to differentiate a circular motion with a rotational motion. Explain with some real life examples.

Comment: But still you haven't answer to my original question...See question title to answer.

Comment: You answer your own question in the second sentence.  What is that troubles you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely circular motion means that the centre of gravity of the body moves in a circular path while the orientation of the body is fixed.

Purely rotational motion means that the orientation of the body rotates while its centre of gravity remains fixed.

The movement of the stone on a string is a combination of both circular and rotational movement, as is the movement of the Earth around the Sun.

For a movement to be circular but not rotational, the alignment of the body must remain fixed as it moves around the central point. Imagine placing a small compass somewhere on a spinning disc. The compass will perform circular motion around the centre of the disc, and it will also move rotationally. However, the compass needle will remain pointing north as the disc rotates, so the compass needle will be performing circular motion around the centre of the disc but not rotational motion.

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that in general the expression 'circular motion' is used to refer to motion of a point or a point mass  along a circle, whereas the expression 'rotational motion' tends to be used for spinning motion of an extended body.

Rotation is the more inclusive of the two. You can treat 'circular motion' as a sub-category of 'rotational motion'. That is: if you have a geometric point, and it is moving along the perimeter of a circle, then there is nothing odd in describing that as rotating motion.

Incidentally, 'spinning' has a narrow meaning. The word 'spinning' is appropriate when the rotational motion of an extended body is around an axis that goes through that body's center of mass, and the required centripetal force is provided by the structural integrity of that body.

Summerizing: 'rotational motion' is a blanket expression that can be used both for circular motion and spinning.

The common center of mass of the Earth and Moon is inside the Earth, about 1700 kilometers below the Earth surface.

The short name for common-center-of-mass-of-the-Earth-and-Moon is:
'Earth-Moon barycenter'.

It is the Earth-Moon barycenter that is orbiting the Sun.

We think of the center of mass of the Earth as a *point*. The center of mass of the Earth is in circular motion around the Earth-Moon barycenter.

We think of the *day* as a manifestation of the Earth's rotation.

Comment: But still you haven't answer to my original question...See question title to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In astronomy, “rotation” refers to the motion of a body about an axis passing through itself whereas “revolution” refers to the motion of one body around another body. For example, the daily cycle of day and night is due to the rotation of the Earth about an axis through the north and south poles, whereas the annual cycle of seasons is due to the revolution of the Earth around the Sun.

Note that the Earth’s orbit around the Sun is not a circle, so revolutionary motion is not necessarily circular motion.

The stone on a string is like a tidally locked planet or moon. It is revolving with a circular motion about whatever the string is attached to, and it is also rotating about an axis through itself. It completes one rotation per revolution, so its “day” is the same as its “year”.

Comment: But still you haven't answer to my original question...See question title to answer.

Comment: @AmanTiwari “Is this type of motion rotational or circular ?”. It is both. I will add a paragraph to my answer.